# JQuery selector on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger something when I click on a certain class within a div.

I tried this

```
$("div .event").click(function() {
    alert($( this ).text());
});
```

And

```
$("div").on("click", $('.event'), function() {
    alert($( this ).text());        
}); 

//Or 
$(".SimpleCalendar .event").click(function() {
    alert($( this ).text());
}); 
//I do not even know what this is supposed to do ...
$(".SimpleCalendar tbody tr td div .event").click(function() {
    alert($( this ).text());
});
```

And many more but still can not figure out why this is not working

My HTML is the following : 
[image]

Comment: The `div` element has the class, so you should remove the space between the selectors in your first example: `$("div.event").click(fn)`. Alternatively, if the table is dynamically loaded, you need to use a delegated event handler: `$('.SimpleCalendar').on('click', 'div.event', fn);`

Comment: `div .event` targets elements with the class `event` nested in a `div`. `div.event` targets a `div` that also has a class `event`. You want the latter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` that you're selecting is the one that has the class `.event`, not a descendant of it. Therefore the correct selector is `div.event`. Try this:

```
$("div.event").click(function() {
    alert($( this ).text());
});
```

Or just:

```
//Warning: if elements unlike the div also have the event class then stick to 
//the above as the selector is more specific
$(".event").click(function() {
    alert($( this ).text());
});
```

And don't forget that each of these options should be in DOM ready like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.event").click(function() {
        alert($( this ).text());
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were making use of parent descendent selector, since `event` class is on the `div` itself and not its descendent your selector was incorrect.

One of these should work for you

Try this

```
$("div.event").click(function() {
    alert($( this ).text());
});
```

or,

```
$(".SimpleCalendar").on("click", '.event', function() {
    alert($( this ).text());        
});
```

For more information on choosing right selectors please see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)